# Resilience4j Retry -> how to log the request input along with event while logging retry count?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, retry-logic, resilience4j-retry

I am using RegistryEventConsumer Bean in order to add event consumers to any Retry instance and logging the event to know how many times a specific endpoint got retried in case of any issues with the endpoint. below is the snippet.

```
@Bean
public RegistryEventConsumer<Retry> myRetryRegistryEventConsumer() {

    return new RegistryEventConsumer<Retry>() {
        @Override
        public void onEntryAddedEvent(EntryAddedEvent<Retry> entryAddedEvent) {
            entryAddedEvent.getAddedEntry().getEventPublisher()
               .onEvent(event -> LOG.info(event.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onEntryRemovedEvent(EntryRemovedEvent<Retry> entryRemoveEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEntryReplacedEvent(EntryReplacedEvent<Retry> entryReplacedEvent) {

        }
    };
}
```

Log Entries look like below

```
2020-10-26T13:00:19.807034700+01:00[Europe/Berlin]: Retry 'backendA', waiting PT1S until attempt '1'. Last attempt failed with exception 'org.abc.exception.MyCustomException: call to http://localhost:8080/endpointA is failed :connect error

2020-10-26T13:00:19.912028800+01:00[Europe/Berlin]: Retry 'backendA', waiting PT2S until attempt '2'. Last attempt failed with exception 'org.abc.exception.MyCustomException: call to http://localhost:8080/endpointA is failed :connect error.

2020-10-26T13:00:20.023250+01:00[Europe/Berlin]: Retry 'backendA' recorded a failed retry attempt. Number of retry attempts: '3'. Giving up. Last exception was: 'org.abc.exception.MyCustomException: call to http://localhost:8080/endpointA is failed :connect error
```

i would like to log the request input which my endpoint takes(lets say it takes Student object with name , id ,age as input ) along with the event . how to achieve this?

1.a) the expectation is to customize the logging and it should something like below.

```
Retry 'backendA', waiting PT1S until attempt '1'. Last attempt failed for url http://localhost:8080/endpointA for input : "Student ("Arun", A11,18)" with exception 'org.abc.exception.MyCustomException: call to http://localhost:8080/endpointA is failed :connect error
```

1.b) and How to capture the metrics?